# Matlab JavaBuilder jar in Eclipse- missing mkl.dll?

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, dll

I've been given some jars generated by the `Matlab JavaBuilder` by some colleagues. Some work fine when I use them in my Eclipse project, but a new one fails with this error:

```
libmwblas: load error: mkl.dll
```

And a message about the dll not being found. When I look in the Matlab Compiler Runtime bin folder there is a `mkl.dll` in there.

Any suggestions as to why Matlab can't or won't see the dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JARs are using JNI and trying to resolve the required DLL.

Option one is to resolve this is by adding `/bin` folder you mentioned to your Windows `PATH` so that Java is able to resolve this (and probably some other) DLLs.

Another (cleaner for development purposes) option is to configure Eclipse by specifying Native library location for the JAR which attempts to load DLLs. Go to `Java Build Path` of your project, then find the appropriate JAR in `Libraries` tab, then expand it and set `Native library location`.